# Уменьшение размера программы, ошибка 0xc0000018 при запуске

Tags: ассемблер

Хочу уменьшить размер скомпилированной программы. Для этого запускаю линковщик с ключом `/ALIGN:256`, как советует Iczelion. Программа компилируется с ворнингом и не запускается: возникает ошибка `0xC0000018`.

В чем дело? На виртуалке с Win XP все работает так, как писал Iczelion, проблема только на Win 7.

Больше к этому вопросу добавить нечего, т.к. даже непонятно, что произошло, а автор не рассказывает про возможные подводные камни.

Comment: В 7-ке вполне может быть другой загрузчик, который не любит выравнивание на 256.

Comment: какой ассемблер? масм? и какое предупреждение?

Comment: Да, масм. ALIGN specified without /DRIVER or /UXD; image may not run